# Typescript: method is undefined when implementing an interface

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have an interface

```
export interface IFilterable{
passesFilter(f : string, isFilter: boolean): boolean;
}
```

That I want to use to filter things in Angular2 pipe. 
It's implemented like this:

```
import {IFilterable} from './i-filterable';
import {Contains} from '../helpers/pipe-helpers';

export class Server extends Dto implements IFilterable {
name: string;
hostname: string;
ips: string;
operatingSystem: string;
sitesCount: number;
databasesCount: number;

passesFilter(f: string, isFilter: boolean): boolean {
    console.log('in server');
    if (!f || f === '') return isFilter;
    f = f.toLowerCase();

    return Contains(this.name, f) ||
        Contains(this.hostname, f) ||
        Contains(this.ips, f) ||
        Contains(this.operatingSystem, f);
}
}
```

Contains function being imported.

The pipe looks like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Contains} from '../helpers/pipe-helpers';
import {IFilterable} from '../models/i-filterable';

@Pipe({ name: 'serverFilter' })
export class ServerFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: IFilterable[], search: string, isFilter: boolean):      IFilterable[] {
     console.log(search + ' search' + isFilter + values);
    return values.filter(value => {
    console.log(value.passesFilter);
    return value.passesFilter(search, isFilter)
  });
 }
}
```

The second console.log in the pipe prints undefined, and the one in passesFilter never even gets called. I also get en error

```
TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter
```

Am I doing something wrong, or are interfaces not really usable like that in TS?

Edit: Implementing same thing with an abstract class.

```
export abstract class Dto {
abstract passesFilter(f: string, isFilter: boolean): boolean;
}
```

Server

```
import {Dto} from './dto';
import {Contains} from '../helpers/pipe-helpers';

export class Server extends Dto {
name: string;
hostname: string;
ips: string;
operatingSystem: string;
sitesCount: number;
databasesCount: number;

passesFilter(f: string, isFilter: boolean): boolean {
    console.log('in server');
    if (!f || f === '') return isFilter;
    f = f.toLowerCase();

    return Contains(this.name, f) ||
        Contains(this.hostname, f) ||
        Contains(this.ips, f) ||
        Contains(this.operatingSystem, f);
}
}
```

pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Dto} from '../models/dto';

@Pipe({ name: 'serverFilter' })
export class ServerFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(values: Dto[], search: string, isFilter: boolean): Dto[] {
console.log(search + ' search' + isFilter + values);
return values.filter(value => {
  console.log(value.passesFilter);
  return value.passesFilter(search, isFilter)
});
 }
}
```

pipe-helpers

```
export function Contains(val: string, cmp: string) {
    return val ? val.toLowerCase().indexOf(cmp) >= 0 : false;
}
```

Comment: Could you please create a plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't see the input of your pipe.. maybe that `values` aren't from type `IFilterable` ?!
anyway i would check values before using it.. maybe its undefined during first pipe round..

```
@Pipe({ name: 'serverFilter' })
export class ServerFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(values: IFilterable[], search: string, isFilter: boolean): IFilterable[] {
      console.log(search + ' search' + isFilter + values);
      if (!values || !values.length) return []; // check that input !

      return values.filter(value => {
         if (!value || !value.passesFilter) return false; // check that value !

         console.log(value.passesFilter);
         return value.passesFilter(search, isFilter)
      });
   }
}
```

And a hint for you:

`if (!f || f === '') return isFilter;`

this check is redundant.. `!''` is true.

**UPDATE**

Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/IhM4rKqD3VvEZVBdimzK?p=preview

Comment: Hey, sorry for responding so late. I updated TS to version 2 and Angular to release version as well. I tried doing it again with an interface and an abstract class and got the same result.
All the values print fine that you said to check. And the array is of type Server and server implements IFilterable. I get the array from a service that returns an observable of Server[].
 Code suggestion even lets me select the passesFilter method. But when I run it I get an error in the console that value.passesFilter is not a function.

Comment: It doesn't work even if I inherit the method from a superclass, that is not abstract.

Comment: please do this in your pipe: `console.dir(values);` to see that incoming array and verify whats in that array..

Comment: see my edit.. added a demo plunker. :) hope it helps.

Comment: does your service create that `Server[]` with `new Server()` or comes it from a JSON format? in this case there will be of course no functions inside..

Comment: Whew, it comes from JSON. How do I make sure it has functions then?

Comment: You have to create a server object `new Server()` and then assign those variables to it.. otherwise its only an data-object without your functions!! better way would be to paste that data-object into the servers `constructor` and do that assignment in your class..

Comment: Wow, I really didn't know that about javascript. Pretty sure it would be working fine in C#. Thanks for this! I already made 4 different pipes that do the filtering inside them, so reimplementing the data extraction from json for all the entities I have would be way too much work to do for something, that's already working. I appreciate the measures you took to help me though!

Comment: Problem is the difference between compile-time and run-time.. during compile-time YOU SAY its an object of that type `Server` and intellisense will show you that functions and so on.. but during run-time its just an data-object came from any DB or whatever and your code TRIES to handle it like an `Server`-object ..

Comment: Well it could throw an error if it couldn't bind something to the JSON. Seems like that would be more reasonable behaviour, imo.

Comment: That's Javascript! :) At run-time there are no "types" left .. you can assign everything to everything ..

Comment: I know that I usually hate doing stuff that I'm bad at (JS in this case), but do people actually enjoy programming in it?